# How do you use Spring Circuit Breaker with Cache Manager?

Tags: spring, spring-data-redis, spring-cache, circuit-breaker, redis-cache

I've seen lots of examples of using things like Netflix's `@HystrixCommand` on service methods, but is it possible to enable a circuit breaker when using one or more `CacheManager` instances? In other words, bypass the Spring cache if the underlying service is unavailable or unstable over time.

Specifically, in our usage of Spring Cache, we simply have a method annotated with `@Cacheable`. Typically with a circuit breaker you specify a fallback, but our fallback is "Dont' use the cache, just execute our method normally". How would we implement that with annotations? Do we need to refactor our code to separate the `CacheManager` calls?

Comment: I am facing the exact problem. Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a custom cache manager and write the circuit breaker logic there.

```
@Component
public  CacheManager CustomCacheManager implements CacheManager  {

    @Override
    public Cache getCache(String s) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> getCacheNames() {
        return null;
    }
}
```